# In Tolkien's works did Sauron attack Eregion personally?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, video-games, shadow-of-mordor

In Monolith's *Shadow of Mordor* we see Sauron personally attacking Eregion and himself killing Celebrimbor.

Did this happen in any of Tolkien's writings?

Answer (score 16):

**Yes**

In the *[Unfinished Tales of Numenor and Middle-earth](https://books.google.com/books?id=5t4vfhasRVcC&pg=PT149&dq=eregion%20celebrimbor&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AFHdVPioC4ecNoWNgYgP&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=eregion%20celebrimbor&f=false)* Chapter IV: *The History of Galadriel and Celeborn*, we see Sauron's reaction to Celebrimbor rebelling against Sauron's 'help' and hiding the elven-rings (*emphasis mine*):

> When Sauron learned of the repentance an revolt of Celebrimbor his disguise fell an his wrath was revealed; and gathering a great force he moved over Calenardhon (Rohan) to the invasion of Eriador in the year 1695.
>
> ...
>
> At last the attackers broke into Eregion with ruin and devastation, and capture the chief object of Sauron's assault, the House of the Mirdain, where were their smithies and their treasures. *Celebrimbor, desperate, himself withstood Sauron on the steps of the great door of the Mirdain; but he was grappled and taken captive, and the House was ransacked.* There Sauron took the Nine Rings and other lesser works of the Mirdain; but the Seven and the Three he could not fin. Then Celebrimbor was put to torment, and Sauron learned from him where the Seven were bestowed. This Celebrimbor revealed, because neither the Seven nor the Nine did he value as he valued the Three; the Seven and the Nine were made with Sauron's aid, whereas the Three were made by Celebrimbor alone, with a different power an purpose.
>
> ...
>
> *Concerning the Three Rings Sauron could learn nothing from Celebrimbor; and he had him put to death.*

So it doesn't say specifically that Sauron personally killed Celebrimbor, but he did indeed personally fight him in Eregion. So this, at least, is an accurate part of *Shadow of Mordor*'s storyline, though the timing of his death in the game's events seems to be off. According to the [Lord of the Rings wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Celebrimbor), Celebrimbor did not die until S.A. 1697, so he was apparently tortured for quite a long time.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds; good answer

Comment: Great answer :) how on earth did celebrimbor withstand sauron :o

Comment: @user31546 It's not unheard of. Celebrimbor was born in Aman, which means he was a powerful Elf-lord; in *The Silmarillion*, we see other powerful Elf-lords single-handedly killing *multiple* Balrogs, and at least one holding their own against Morgoth (Sauron's boss) himself

Comment: Was sauron the one to grapple him?

Comment: I re read it of course it was sauron who grappled him :)

Comment: @JasonBaker: It should be noted that the power level of a Balrog was somewhat inconsistent in Tolkien's work...